# How to toggle active state in MudBlazorNavMenu without relying on URL changes

Tags: mudblazor

I am currently working on a project using MudBlazor and implementing a navigation menu with MudNavMenu and MudNavLink. I'm trying to dynamically toggle the active state of MudNavLink elements based on user interactions without relying on URL changes.

```
<MudNavMenu Rounded="true" Margin="Margin.Normal" Color="Color.Secondary" Class="pa-2" Style="width:14.2rem">
@foreach (HelpSearchEntry entry in _searchResults)
{
    <MudNavLink @onclick="() => displayResult(entry)">
        <MudIcon Style="font-size:15px" Class="d-inline" Icon="@GetIconOfOrigin(entry.Type)" Title="Favorite" />
        @entry.OptionText
    </MudNavLink>
}
```

In the displayResult function, I attempted to manipulate the element to add the 'active' class. However, it didn't yield the expected results.

How to successfully toggle the active state programmatically in MudBlazorNavMenu?